Converting SystemVerilog Structs Into C/C++ Structs
Somewhere in my environment, there's a large file that contains (among other stuff) many System Verilog structs of 64 bits,
e.g.:
typedef struct packed {  
  logic [63:63]  my_field_1;  
  logic [62:60]  my field_2;  
  ...  
  logic [0:0]  my field_n;
} my_struct_1_t;

I need a way to convert this into a C/CPP structs with bit fields.
e.g.
struct my_struct_1_t {  
  uint64_t my_field_n:1;//This is the LSB
  ...  
  uint64_t my_field_2:3;  
  uint64_t my_field_1:1;//This is the MSB
};

I have no idea how to do that, so would appreciate any help (In any language / shell script etc.).
Thanks!

Verilog probably has well-defined bit-fields, unlike C, so there's not necessarily a 1 to 1 translation here. C does not need to support uint64_t bit-fields and in case it does, it is still not well-defined if uint64_t my_field_n:1; is bit 63 or bit 0.

@Lundin - what do you mean that C doesn't have a well defined bit-field? I have worked with it for years... And from my experiences the order is also well defined (LSB on top .. MSB at the bottom). Also, uint64_t exists if you add #include <inttypes.h>

This sounds like something the verilog compiler should be able to generate, albeit with a metric ton of macros...

The section about bit-fields in the C standard is simply too vague and with too much implementation-defined aspects to be of any use; compilers can simply implement bit-fields more or less as they please and that makes them non-portable and unpredictable. See for example this.  Also the C standard only covers types bool, signed int and unsigned int but uint64_t is not likely one of those.

@Botje - interesting direction... I though more in the direction of text manipulation (going over the original file, manipulate the content, and print it to a .h file), but will explore your idea as well. Any more clues on what keywords to search in the compiler documentation?

No idea. I was a consumer of such generated header files but not involved in the production.

Thanks @Botje - will try asking the compiler people in my company.

Please note that this shouldn't be tagged C and C++ at once since the languages are different. C++ at least attempted to salvage the broken standard with the introduction of std::bitset. C is intent on remaining forever broken, apparently.

@Lundin - regarding the bitfield - very interesting, I had no idea...
Thanks for letting me know.
But let's assume I'm always using the same compiler (gcc/g++), so I'm not concerned about being portable. I know from past experience that gcc yields deterministic results regarding bit field location.

@Benny80 If you can find some gcc documentation about the "ABI" for the particular target and refer to that one, it should be perfectly possible to generate something that works under those specific conditions. However, writing the code relying on bit masks and bit shifts instead would make it portable, but then you might have to drop the struct.

There is also the question how these "logic" variables are supposed to be presented to the hardware. Can you write individual bits? Bytes? Words? Quadwords? Best to stick to an opaque char[] blob with an atomic read/write operation.

@Botje - HW can access individual bits.

@Lundin - I'm starting to think you're right, and bit masks & shifts are more robust.
But I'm leaving the question open since if somebody raises a good way to do the conversion I asked - it will work fine for my needs.

And how are you supposed to update my_field_2, which consists of three bits? LSB to MSB? MSB to LSB? From the middle out? Is there a latch register you need to prod to send the update?

@Botje the HW does a read-modify-write. And my C/C++ program just needs access to this struct, to be able to parse some raw data (I get the full 64-bit data, and I need to know which field is at which location).

Are you trying to translate SystemVerilog code to C/C++, or are you trying to interact with SystemVerilog executing code in a simulation?

@dave_59 - just translate the structs from one language to another. No interactions with simulation whatsoever.

As many of the comments suggest, C bit fields can be a bit dicey to use. There's no defined in-memory representation, so it's a matter of experimentation with compilers and, probably, a bunch of #pragmas to get a workable combination.
Three options exist.

Write code

You could write code to explicitly manipulate the data to isolate each field's bits, and create a structure that simply has ints / bools (no bit fields) in it to contain the parsed data. A simple function to isolate and return any given bit / bit sequence as an int64 would make this a lot easier.

Use ASN.1

This is a serialisation technology that has multiple wire formats. The one of interest is uPER - unaligned packed encoding rules. You can relatively easily write an ASN.1 schema that - used with uPER - would be able to generate and parse your data. For example, in uPER a BOOLEAN turns into a single bit. An INTEGER (0..15) becomes 4 bits. If you had an ASN.1 PDU such as
MyStruct ::= SET OF
{
   my_field_1 [0] BOOLEAN,          -- 1 bit
   my_field_2 [1] INTEGER (0..7),   -- 3 bits as an integer
   etc
}

the ASN.1 compiler would generate C/C++ code that parses / writes that in uPER wireformat, and that will just so happen to match your data structure. It's a bit like option 1, except that the ASN.1 compiler is writing the code and we're exploiting the uPER wireformat specification to "line up" with your data.
This ASN.1 compiler is probably up to the job, and I can recommend this web page for an overview, this playground to try things out, and Dubuisson's book available here for free. You can also convert ASN.1 schema to XML schema (XSD), which gives you more options for passing the data on with both you and the recipient working off the same schema.

Use CSN.1

Whereas ASN.1 is "Abstract syntax notation #1", CSN.1 is "Concrete Syntax Notation #1".
ASN.1 is all about defining what information needs to be exchanged without a care in the world about how it's represented on the wire (hence the proliferation of binary and text wireformats for it). CSN.1 is all about defining what information needs to be exchanged, and be totally explicit about how it is to be represented on the wire.
Thus with CSN.1 one can define any arbitrary bit stream, and have a compiler automatically build code that can interpret and write your bit stream. However, there's far fewer tools for this, and things often go wrong. If you are interested in this approach, you're probably looking at one of the commercial tools (such as Objective Systems inc, whose ASN.1 compiler now also handles CSN.1 I think).
Recommendation: I'd use the ASN.1 approach. The nice thing is that, once you've got that working, your C code can easily re-emit the data in a variety of different formats including XML. That might make life a bit easier if there are onward systems to receive data.
The ASN.1 compiler from Objective Systems now also supports JER (JSON encoding rules), so it can send data web-wards pretty easily without the recipient necessarily having to know anything about ASN.1 as such.
If you don't feel like experimenting with ASN.1 uPER, I'd go with writing some code to explicitly handly bits yourself. It's boring boilerplate code, but it's fairly simply and sure. It'd be a lot better than relying on a C compiler to always lay out bit fields in the way you want.
